# How do I expose the Kubernetes UI Dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes

Per the documentation at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/web-ui-dashboard/
I ran :

```
kubectl create -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Then I tried running this to expose the service

```
cluster/kubectl.sh expose svc/kubernetes
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
error: couldn't retrieve selectors via --selector flag or introspection: the service has no pod selector set
See 'kubectl expose -h' for help and examples.
```

I have looked at the examples but can't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
kubernetes# cluster/kubectl.sh get all
NAME             CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
svc/kubernetes   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP   7h

kubernetes# cluster/kubectl.sh get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   kube-dns-806549836-r6wtk                0/3       Pending   0          7h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-2396447444-9675d   0/1       Pending   0          6h
```

Answer (score 1):

To get access to the dashboard, usually you would just type:

`kubectl cluster-info`

Which then gives you all the required urls for accessing your cluster.

Comment: Its on localhost. THis server is hosted in a datacenter.
Kubernetes master is running at https://localhost:6443/
KubeDNS is running at https://localhost:6443//api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns/proxy

Comment: How do I make it so that I can see it from my home?

Comment: The cluster-info shown urls are exposed per definition. If you installed everything using internal IPs only, you will have to add some routing/loadbalancer/proxy solution.

Comment: Could you send a link to instructions on the easiest one of those to do? I suppose proxy?

Comment: @FrankBarcenas You can use `kubectl proxy` to access dashboard. Just run `kubectl proxy` and it will open kubernetes dashboard in your default browser.

Comment: @HardikModha The machine is in a datacenter.